# Is there a function in C++/C that asks the user for a file as input by opening a file explorer window for them to select the file?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

As the title says, I'm looking for a function on C++/C that will open a file explorer window to get a file as input from the user's system.
I couldn't find much by googling only the system() function, but it doesn't really do what I need it to do (or maybe I don't know how to use it).

I only properly tried the System() function because that's all I found, all the other stuff is about filenames which I don't need, and well it's not the function I'm looking for

Comment: C++ has no concept of file explorer, you have to use OS-specific APIs.

Comment: What would be some?

Comment: Or a cross-platform GUI library that abstracts away those OS-specific API calls

Comment: @Burd44 [GetOpenFileNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for Windows.

Comment: @Quimby thank you, this is exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: @Burd44 you should have specified the platform (Windows in your case) and put the right tags (WINAPI)

Comment: C/C++ define no GUI items of any kind, not even graphics. Only console I/O.

Answer (score 4):

From comments I am assuming you want Windows only method

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

string fileDialog(LPCSTR fileType) {
    OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
    char szFile[300];
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = fileType;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn)) {
        return ofn.lpstrFile;
    }
    return "";
}

int main()
{
    cout << fileDialog("Any File\0*") << endl;
    cout << fileDialog("EXE File\0*.exe") << endl;
    cout << fileDialog("MP4 File\0*.mp4") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is little point in calling a Unicode API and converting the result to ANSI. You should either leave the result in Unicode (ie, return a `wstring` and pass it to `std::wcout`), or else call the ANSI version of the API to begin with (`GetOpenFileNameA()`) if you want an ANSI output.

Comment: Use wide character APIs in Windows when dealing with file names. It's better at handling paths that contain non-English characters.

Comment: I copied this code from my very old injector. Some people inject strangely named DLLs. That's why I used GetOpenFileName().

Comment: @rooteduser more accurately, why you had used `GetOpenFileNameW()`

Comment: @paddy if you use C++17 or later, it's even better to use `std::filesystem::path` instead of strings.

Comment: Should be using Unicode and `IFileDialog`, it's the 21st Century now